# Mozilla Animation Kit not working

Tags: css, webkit, transform, mozilla

I am trying to animate an element and make it appear on button click.
The below code works perfectly fine in Chrome, but doesn't work for Mozilla Firefox.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

CSS Class for animation:

```
.moz-trial{
    -moz-animation:moz-trial 2s;
    -webkit-animation: moz-trial 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes moz-trial {

    0%   {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform: translateX(-20px);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-20px);
    }
    50%   {
        opacity: 0.8;
       -moz-transform: translateX(+20px);
       -webkit-transform: translateX(+20px);
    }
    100%   {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: translateX(0px);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
    }
}
```

My JS code on button click:

```
$('#open_drawer').on('click',function(){    
   $('#questions_menu_drawer').removeClass('hidden').addClass('moz-trial');
});
```

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/88ogrojy/

Comment: Post your html or even better make a FIDDLE

Comment: Hey Richa, unfortunately I cannot post the html, as our designs are private

Comment: Well in that case it will be difficult for us to help it out

Comment: if you apply the css and js to any div with the id -> questions_menu_drawer, the resulting output should be an animation

Comment: So you mean we should write html and then try to help you. Great

Comment: i am making a test fiddle

Comment: hey richa, the fiddle is attached now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add following to your code.

Check this 2 fiddles i tested

**[FIDDLE 1](http://jsfiddle.net/88ogrojy/3/)**  **[FIDDLE 2](http://jsfiddle.net/bkmL3z40/4/)**

```
@keyframes moz-trial {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform: translateX(-20px);
        transform: translateX(-20px);
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0.8;
        -moz-transform: translateX(+20px);
        transform: translateX(+20px);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: translateX(0px);
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }
}
```

Comment: @gunj_desai Glad to have helped :)